# change mongodb based on user nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, mongoose, database

I have a different database for each and every user. The name of the database is same as username. i have an another database call 'auth' which contain username and password for each and every user for login.

So initially nodejs is connected to auth database and based on user login, database should change accordingly.

To do this, i created two database connection conn (for auth) and conn2 (for user specific database). After login the user should redirect to my home page with data specified in user specific database.

However, after login the user is redirecting to home page with "undefined_dashboard" as database. i get it that the problem is due to async programming.

How to resolve it?

i have attach the sample analogy code in the question itself.

folder management:

```
|node_modules
|routes
|--dashboard.js
|views
|--dashboard_span.ejs
|--index.ejs
|app.js
|models.js
|package.json
```

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');


var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/auth');

var User = conn.model('User', new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
},{collection:'user'}));

var app = express();
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.get('/', function(request, response){
    response.render('index.ejs');
});

app.post('/', function(request, response){
    User.findOne({username:request.body.username},function(error, user){
        if (!user) {
            response.render('index.ejs', {error: "Incorrect email / password"});
        }
        else {
            if (user.password === request.body.password) {
                global.username = user.username;
                response.redirect('/dashboard');
            }
            else {
                response.render('index.ejs', {error: "aIncorrect email / password"});
            }
        }
        global.client_name = global.username;


    });
});

database_name = 'mongodb://localhost/'+global.client_name+'_dashboard';
console.log(database_name)
module.exports.conn2 = mongoose.createConnection(database_name);

app.use(require('./routes/dashboard'));


app.listen(3000, function(request, response){
    console.log(database_name)
    console.log("Server is running at Port 3000");
});
```

models.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = require('./app');

module.exports.Suspicious = app.conn2.model('Suspicious', new mongoose.Schema({
    youtube: Number,
    twitter: Number,
    googleplus: Number,
    facebook: Number,
},{collection: 'sm_total_suspicious_counter'}));
```

dashboard.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var models = require('../models');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/dashboard', function(request, response){
    models.Suspicious.findOne({},function(error, suspicious_data){
        if (error) { response.send("<h1>Database's fault. The damn thing is not sending data.</h1>") }
        response.render('dashboard_span.ejs', {suspicious:suspicious_data});        
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

dashboard_span.ejs:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Testing</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= suspicious %>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form method='post'>
  Username:<br>
  <input type="text" name="username" id='username'>
  <br>
  Password:<br>
  <input type="password" name="password" id='password'>
  <button name="submit">Sign In</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to create a separate database for each user? This is really bad practice.

Comment: each user contains a lot of information (say 20 collections). so cant put all that information in one database. However, if you have a better alternative, i am all ears.

Comment: Each user has 20 collections? Wow...

Comment: yeah..i know...
but just out of curiosity...why having more than one database is not a good design?

Comment: When you are creating multiple databases, you are creating multiple instances of your database connections (which consumes a lot of resources) or you are constantly switching your database connection (but making your app slower). How many users will use the app?

Comment: Also, why is it not possible to store the data of all users in a single collection and adding the userId in the documents (so you can filter them)? So you will only need a single database with 20 collections.

Comment: I think you are confusing the whole concept of NoSQL data modelling, why create a database for each user? Data for all users can go into a single collection and MongoDB's scalability means you can store 1 billion+ documents in the database.

Comment: I agree with @chridam but if you still want multiple databases, I can provide you with a simple setup to get you started.

Comment: But for that i need to change in underline software written in python. But it does sound like a good idea.

Comment: @Rob Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29585234/3398302). He is trying to accomplish the same. That should get you going.